# Whole page reloads when navigating using Turbo in Rails application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I recently began working on a documentation site using Ruby on Rails and Turbo (repository is [here](https://github.com/PureChart/purechart-documentation), and the website is [here](https://docs.purechart.org/articles/getting-started)), and I'm having a slight issue with navigation.

When I press the links in the left sidebar, the content on the right side of the screen *is* correctly replaced. Here's some relevant code -

**articles.html.erb**

```
<div class='docs-split'>
    <div class='sidebar'>
        <div>
            ...

            <div class='links padding-top'>
                <%= link_to render(:partial => 'shared/primary_navigation_link', locals: { title: "Getting Started", path: "getting-started" }), 'getting-started' %>
                <%= link_to render(:partial => 'shared/primary_navigation_link', locals: { title: "Types of Charts", path: "types-of-charts" }), 'types-of-charts' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='content'>
        <%= turbo_frame_tag "article", src: article_path(params[:title] ? params[:title] : "getting-started") do %>
            
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
require 'github/markup'

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def open_article
    title = Rails.root.to_s + "/app/markdown/" + params[:title] + ".md"
    @content = ActionController::Base.render inline: GitHub::Markup.render(title, File.read(title))
  end
end
```

**open_article.html.erb**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "article" do %>
    <%= @content %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => redirect('/articles/getting-started')
  get 'articles/:title', to: 'articles#index'

  # Embedded article GET route
  get ':title', to: 'articles#open_article', as: 'article'
end
```

What I expect to occur is that only the content inside the Turbo tag will change while the rest of the HTMl remains the same and the navigation link styles will transition as specified by my CSS. However, what seems to occur instead is that all of the HTML is reloaded, which means the CSS transitions that are supposed to happen when navigation links are clicked don't happen and the Turbo tag content appears to blink twice.

I'm new to Rails and Hotwire/Turbo, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: add `data-turbo-frame="article"` to your links https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes#data-attributes